# User inputs to Dynamic Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

[image]User entries all captured and stored in array. Array output should display in a dynamic table. Dynamic table should contain edit and delete options. If the entries are more than 3 then table should contain prev and next options. Age should be calculated automatically if the date of birth input is given by the user.

I almost finished. But it is not displaying the row (not adding row) below.

Please help me to come front

```js
<script>
//Email Validation Part


 
//Name Validation Part

function validateName(Name) 
    {
 var nam = document.form1.Name.value;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
    if(document.form1.Name.value.match(letters))  
  {
  return true;  
  }
 else  
  {  
  alert('Please input alphabet characters only');  
  return false;  
  }
    }
 
//Basic Validation Part

function validate()


 {
 
 if( document.form1.Name.value == "" )
  {
  alert( "Please provide your name!" );
  document.form1.Name.focus() ;
  return false;
  }
 else
  {
  var nameret = validateName();
  if(nameret == false)
   {
   return false;
   }
  }
  
  
 
    var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
    if(pattern.test(Email)){         
  return true;   
    }else{   
  alert("Please check your Email again..."); 
  return false;
    }

 
 /*if( document.form1.Email.value == "" )
  {
  alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
  document.form1.Email.focus() ;
  return false;
  }
 else
  {
  var mailret = validateEmail();
  if( ret == false )
   {
   return false;
   }
  }*/
 if( document.form1.Phone.value == "" || isNaN( document.form1.Phone.value ) || document.form1.Phone.value.length != 12 )
  {
  alert( "Please provide the mobile number with country code" );
  document.form1.Phone.focus() ;

  }
 if( document.form1.City.value == "-1" )
  {
  alert( "Please provide your City!" );

  }
 
  var today=new Date();
  var t=today.getFullyear();
 if( document.form1.Date.value == "" || document.form1.Date.value>t) {
  alert("Please Enter the valid Date of Birth");
  
 }

    if(form.Gender[0].checked == false && form.Gender[1].checked == false)
    {
    alert("Gender must be choosen");
 
    }
 
 
}
 
//Age Calculation Part

function calcAge() {
            var date = new Date(document.getElementById("dateofbirth").value);
            var today = new Date();

            var timeDiff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - date.getTime());
            var age1 = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365;
   if(age1<0){
   alert("Please give the valid date of birth")
   return false;}
            return parseInt(age1);
        }
        //Compares calculated age with minimum age and acts according to rules//
//For adding rows
function addRow() {

validate();
debugger;
    var myName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var myDateOfBirth = document.getElementById("dateofbirth").value;
 var myAge = calcAge();
 var myEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
 var myGender = document.getElementsByClassName("gender").value;
 var myCity = document.getElementById("city").value;
 var myEditDelete = document.getElementsByClassName("editdelete");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
 
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 var mySno = rowCount;      
 
   
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= mySno;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName;
 row.insertCell(2).innerHTMl= myDateOfBirth;
 row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= myAge;
 row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= myEmail;
 row.insertCell(5).innerHTML= myGender;
 row.insertCell(6).innerHTML= myCity;
 row.insertCell(7).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" class="editdelete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)"><input type="button" class="editdelete" value="Edit"onclick="Javacsript:editRow(this)">';
   
   var personObj= new Object();
   personObj[0]=mySno;
   personObj[1]=myName;
   personObj[2]=myDateOfBirth;
   personObj[3]=myAge;
   personObj[4]=myEmail;
   personObj[5]=myGender;
   personObj[6]=myCity;
   personObj[7]=myEditDelete;
   return personObj;
 
   personArray = [];
 for(var i = 0; i<personArray.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("myTableData").innerHTML += personArray[i];
    }
}
 
}

function deleteRow(obj) {
     
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);
    
}
function editRow(obj) {
      
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.editRow(index);
    
}
 






function myReset() {
    document.form1.reset();
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
*
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
body
{
height:1000px;
}
#head
{
width:800px;
height:35px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
#pages
{
height:30px;
width:800px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:right;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
#table
{
width:800px;
height:200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#city
{
width:170px;
}
#btndiv
{
width:800px;
height:100px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}
#add, #reset
{
width:100px;
height:30px;
border-radius:10px;
}
#table2
{
width:730px;

margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:grey;
}
#myTableData
{
width:800px;
height:100px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
    <h1 align="center">Data Entry Form</h1>
</div>
<div id="pages">
 <a href="search.html">search |</a>
 <a href="Entry.html">Entry</a>
</div>
<div>

<form name="form1" onsubmit="validate(this.form)">
<table id="table" cellspacing="50">

<tr>
<td>Name*</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" id="name" required></td>
<td>Email*</td><td><input type="text" name="Email" id="email" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date of Birth*</td><td><input type="date" name="Date" id="dateofbirth" required></td>
<td>Phone</td><td><input type="text" name="Phone" id="phone"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender*</td><td>
<input required type="radio" id="male" class="gender" value="Male" name="Gender">Male&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="radio" class="gender" id="female" value="Female" name="Gender">Female</td>
<td>City*</td><td>
               <select id="city" required>
      <option>select a city</option>
      <option>Delhi</option>
      <option>Mumbai</option>
      <option>Kolkata</option>
      <option>Chennai</option>
      <option>Pune</option>
      <option>Bangalore</option>
      <option>Hyderabad</option>
      <option>Kochin</option>
      </select>
              </td>
</tr>

</table>

<div id="btndiv">
<input id="add" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myDetails(this)">
<button id="reset" onclick="myReset()">Reset</button>
</div>

</form>

<table id="myTableData" onclick="myDetails()">
    <tr>
        <td><b>S.No</b></td>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Date of Birth</b></td>
  <td><b>Age</b></td>
  <td><b>Email</b></td>
  <td><b>Gender</b></td>
  <td><b>City</b></td>
  <td><b>Edit | Delete</b></td>
  
 
    </tr>
</table>





</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `myDetails()` is not defined.

2) Check console to know the errors that helps a lot.

3) There is an error on `line 52`, script tag is written twice.

Comment: Did you resolve all the errors coming in browser console?

Comment: Yes, I used debugger option also. I can post moqup for your reference. But i need atleast 10 reputation.

Comment: You can create a plunkr or fiddle and share the link here.

Comment: Now i got 10 reputation. I posted a moqup for your reference.

Comment: I have some work, will get back to your question asap.